# Odd problems with CheckListBoxes in C#

Tags: c#, iteration, checkedlistbox

I have quite a few check boxes in an application I'm playing with. So, I decided to use a CheckedListBox instead. I iterate through the list with the code below...

```
private void CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            string x = "";
            for (int x = 0; x <= ServicesCheckedListBox3.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                x = x + "Checked Item " + (x + 1).ToString() + " = " +                         ServicesCheckedListBox3.CheckedItems[x].ToString() + "\n";
            }
            Line.Add(x);
        }
    }
```

The out put gives me this...

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].
```

I'm very new and have never seen this. The application runs fine but the out put doesn't come out right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: WinForms. In Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Why are you using a `List<T>` in the first place?

Comment: Well i was tailoring a older program that had most of the functionality built in. The Lists were already there so I used them. Is this bad practice?

Comment: It's good practice, but it's apparently not what you want.

Comment: You should rename your string variable to something else. You have both the string and the int in the loop named `x`. This is very confusing when reading code. Also, when you say 'output', where is that displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string x="";
    foreach(string chk in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        x = x + "Checked Item " + checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(chk).ToString() + " = " + chk + "\n";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(x);
}
```

Comment: I run in my system affter I select item 1 i recive this message "Checked Item 0 = i1"

Comment: I must have something else wrong. Without using the List's I am getting back my hardcoded titles but not the values.

Comment: when you want to retrieve the value from your list use "checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(chk)" as your index("chk" is value of selected item)

Comment: Useing this structure i was able to work out all the kinks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to iterate through CheckedItems

```
foreach(string item in ServicesCheckedListBox3.CheckedItems)
{
    Line.Add(item)
}
```